# how to run anaconda from python subprocess

Tags: python, anaconda, subprocess

I am trying to create subprocess in python which activate conda env then run shell script.  To achieve that I am doing following

```
subprocess.call("""conda activate r_conda && Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")'""", shell=True,  executable="/bin/bash")
```

However, I am getting following error

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to
>   use 'conda activate'.

However I am able achieve this by moving code in shell script as following in test.sh file.

```
conda activate r_conda
Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")'
```

Then I can run following code

```
subprocess.call("""bash -i test.sh""", shell=True)
```

So any one how how to do it without writing shell script?

Comment: first version may use different shell then `bash` - ie shell `sh` - and it may work different then `bash`. But I'm not sure if `call()` doesn't have option to define what shell to use.

Comment: in documentation [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) you can see `"On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh."` . You can try to use `call('bash -c "conda ..."', shell=True)`

Comment: maybe will work `call("conda ...", executable="/bin/bash", shell=True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup the environment that are required to run conda. (which is done through the init scripts like `.bash_profile` if you run it on the command-line)

Maybe try to add this: `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"`

```
subprocess.call("""eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)" && conda activate r_conda && echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV""", shell=True,  executable="/bin/bash")
```

This should print out your Conda environment name - `r_conda`.

Comment: after all searches this is the only answer that helped me. thanks